# Spring Data JPA Querydsl doesn't work with projection

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, projection, querydsl

I have implemented Spring Data JPA and used Querydsl for search conditions. Which works fine with few changes as given in spring docs.

My REST controller method is given below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testdsl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 Iterable<User> index(
@QuerydslPredicate(root = User.class) Predicate predicate)
{
  return userRepository.findAll(predicate);
}
```

and the repository is given below, commented methods give me projected objects nicely.

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>,
QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QUser>
{
  //Collection<OnlyName> findAllProjectedBy();
  //OnlyName findProjectedById(Integer id);

@Override
default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QUser root)
{

    bindings.bind(String.class)
    .first((StringPath path, String value) ->    path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
 }
 }
```

And then I have this projection implemented where I get a subset of the whole entity class which is returned as the response.

```
public interface IUserProjection  {
 //...all required getters..
 }
```

Now I want my Querydsl to return these projected objects. 
Do we have any sample of such combination? I am using spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but you'll need a concrete class...

```
class UserProjection {

  @QueryProjection
  public UserProjection(long id, String name){
     ...
  }

}
```

And then your query would look like (in QueryDSL 3):

```
query.from(QTenant.tenant).list(new QUserProjection(QTenant.tenant.id, QTenant.tenant.name));
```

EDIT:

Query for queryDSL 4 would look like this:

```
List<UserProjection> dtos = query.select(new QUserProjection(QTenant.tenant.id, QTenant.tenant.name))
                              .from(tenant).fetch();
```

Comment: i have used spring query dsl (question edited).. and these seems little different and what is QTenant

Comment: You'd never used it with auto generated Q classes? They're type safe auto generated classes you can use to avoid using string literals

Comment: i use those autogenreated for entity , what about QUserProjection ? do i need to generate it , do you have a sample of this qprojection class ?

Comment: they should get generated the same way if you're already generating QEntity

Comment: and i am using com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLQuery , which doesnt have this limit method...

Comment: and which class  i need to use where list method takes this kind of projection arguement. The one i use JPLQuery list method takes a number which is to restrict number of result.

Comment: my bad, I gave you an example of queryDSL 3, you're probably using queryDSL 4. Check this out: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/reference/html/ch03s02.html